# Selenium Cloud/non-locally

Tags: python, flask, selenium-webdriver

I tried using Vercel to run selenium but it doesn't work. Does anyone know how to run selenium not locally - it can be a method with flask on a website or just cloud using headless - basically any solution to run selenium non-locally.